# Get facebook posts from group from others if I am NOT admin

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-group

SO, I belong to some facebook group. I am not admin and I want to get all posts from that group by others,

Idea is to filter those and get notification when someone posts something that passes filter.
Example, to get notification when post containing string "laptop" is posted.

Like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjaYT.jpg

I tries looking into facebook API but cannot find anything if I am not admin...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/group/feed

You can read the feed of a group with a User Access Token of any user that is member of the group, not sure what you found for Admins but they don't even get mentioned in the docs.

Keep in mind that you need the user_groups permission, and you will most likely not get it approved:

> This permission is granted to apps building a Facebook-branded client on platforms where Facebook is not already available. For example, Android and iOS apps will not be approved for this permission. In addition, Web, Desktop and TV apps will not be granted this permission.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2

Comment: The thing with admins I found here for some similar question.
So, is there way to found way around this permission?

It looks like I'll have to parse HTML of the page to get what I want...

Comment: if you only want to use the app with your own account, you dont need approval. but it will definitely not be possible to create a public app for this.

Comment: and parsing the HTML would be scraping, which is not allowed

Comment: Aha, ok. I just need it for personal use.

Comment: Hey @excrucio how did you end up doing this? Cheers